# Launching failed because directory '/remote_debugger' in the container is empty

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1

I have `dotnet core 3.1` web api application where I am using Visual Studio 2019 `docker` and `docker-compose` tooling feature to run the application.

When I am trying to run the application I am getting below error,

> Launching failed because directory '/remote_debugger' in the container is empty. This might be caused by Shared Drives credentials used by Docker Desktop being out of date. Try resetting the credentials in the Shared Drives page of the Docker Desktop Settings and then restart Docker

[image]

The build is successful and below is the output. I am seeing some error related to `PS` script. Is this the reason?

What credential re-setting I need to do, could someone please suggest?

> C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID linux-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\user1\vsdbg\vs2017u5"
> AuthorizationManager check failed.
> + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
> C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u5 -RuntimeID linux-musl-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\user1\vsdbg\vs2017u5\linux-musl-x64"
> AuthorizationManager check failed.
> + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
> A non-critical error occurred while getting the container(s) ready. Your project(s) will continue to function normally. The error was: The debugger path 'C:\Users\user1\vsdbg\vs2017u5' for Dockerfile 'C:\Users\user1\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Dockerfile' is invalid.
> ========== Debugging ==========
> docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/WebApplication1$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
> bf37df902db3

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using docker desktop with wsl2. And the project I was trying to launch is on net 6.0.
Same popup showed.
I closed the visual studio 22, and started it with **administrative privileges**, Launched the project. And it worked